# How to Re-register all Modern Apps in Windows 8 and 10

Tags: windows, windows-8, modern-ui, windows-10-preview

Sometimes modern apps will not load or open, the icons disappear from the task bar and they don't respond to any tap/click or command. Resulting in some apps returning:

> Windows cannot find ". Make sure you typed the name correctly, and then try again.

[No troubleshooter or workaround will work](http://www.eightforums.com/tutorials/21051-apps-tiles-not-working-responding-fix-windows-8-a.html). My current built of Windows 10 is 9879.

Update: Brink (eightforums.com admin) [added the 15th step after I talked to him](http://www.eightforums.com/tutorials/21051-apps-tiles-not-working-responding-fix-windows-8-a-4.html#post454999) about the solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To solve this [MVP Keith Hill suggested to re-register all of the AppXPackages again](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_tp-windows_store/unable-to-launch-windows-apps/2c6ac3c1-fc6f-489c-893e-9e6d3b028c03) using the next command in the Powershell:

```
Get-AppXPackage | Foreach {Add-AppxPackage -DisableDevelopmentMode -Register "$($_.InstallLocation)\AppXManifest.xml"}
```